# how to display sqlite data in a listview using arrayadapter ? i got the ans in log but i wont used array adapter to display in listview

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

```
//ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,log);
//ls.setAdapter(ad); im using this adapter to display but not working 

ListView ls;
String log;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);

    ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
    for (Contact cn : contacts) {

        log = "Id: " + cn.getID() + " ,Name: " + cn.getUSERNAME()
                + " ,Address: " + cn.getADDRESS() + " ,Phone: "
                + cn.getPHONENUMBER();
        Log.d("Name: ", log);
    }
}
```

Comment: **1** Create an Adapter which uses that List, **2** Pass the Adapeter to the ListView.

Comment: no,  no,  no,  dont use ArrayAdapter, your data model is sqlite db so use [Simple]CursorAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,log);
  ls.setAdapter(ad);  it not working give me a  error

Comment: why do you insist in using ArrayAdapter?

Comment: *Not working* or *gives error* are very broad terms. Can you be please more specific, about the error. If possible, also post the logcat of the error. What @DerGolem said, is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below below tutorial to populate cursor data in Listview

http://androidtuts4u.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-sqlite-and-listview-example.html